# Deal with py2 incompatible syntax in tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a unittest test case in my app which needs to be py2 and py3 compatible.

```py
class MyTest(TestCase):
   def test_pep3102(self):
      def fn(a, b, *, d):
         pass
      
      # do something
      # assert
```

This test case works fine with py3 since py3 supports the signature of `fn` however fails as expected in py2 due to syntax error during module loading

What's the recommended way to deal with this?

I'm thinking of moving it out to a different file and loading it if py > 3 but wanted to know if there's a cleaner solution

Comment: I would probably move it out (also expecting that the Py2 test will go away at some time). If you don't want this, you could use `def fn(*args, **kwargs)` and manually check for the arguments (and raise if there are more than 2 args in Python 3), though that is a bit awkward IMO.